# Python parsing Get API nested JSON object and writing result to CSV

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to parse this json and load into .CSV on daily basis, where we change the date_added to sysdate etc.,and fetch incremental records.

Question: I was able to load to json but i just get top level elements like "has_more,last_val,next_val,    num_returned" and rest is all coming as whole nested object written to csv. How do I disregard top level elements and flatten "**Offers**" object and write all these into individual columns.

```
{
  "has_more": true,
  "last_val": 978360,
  "next_val": 978358,
  "num_returned": 100,
  "offers": [
    {
      "coupon_code": null,
      "date_added": "2020-07-06 15:08:51",
      "description": "4th of July Sales Event! Save on Air Conditioners + Free US Shipping at Heat&Cool - Shop Now!\t\t",
      "featured": true,
      "id": 1027922,
      "merchant_details": {
        "advertiser_id": 9177,
        "countries": [
          "United States"
        ],
        "country_codes": [
          "US"
        ],
        "domain": "heatandcool.com",
        "domains": [
          "heatandcool.com"
        ],
        "favourite": false,
        "id": 77706,
        "merchant_id": 77706,
        "metadata": {
          "description": null,
          "logo": "https://static.TESTlinks.com/images/merchant_logos/advertiser_logo_9177.gif",
          "special_conditions": null
        },
        "name": "HeatAndCool.com",
        "partner_type": null,
        "verticals": [
          "DIY Home Improvement",
          "Appliances",
          "Home"
        ]
      },
      "offer_ends": "2020-07-09 00:00:00",
      "offer_starts": "2020-07-02 00:00:00",
      "offer_type": "sale",
      "period": "finishing_soon",
      "terms": "see website for details",
      "title": "40% OFF heating and air conditioning units with free shipping and returns",
      "url": "https://www.heatandcool.com/sale.html/?TESToffer=1027922"
    },
    {
     ........
     ..........etc.,  
    },
```

**my attempt**

```
import requests
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = "https://authentication.testapis.com/access_token"

payload = {
    "client_id": "xxxxx",
    "client_secret": "xxxxx",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
r = response.json() 
access_token = r.get('access_token') 

print(response.json()['access_token'])

##PRODUCTION
url1="https://private-testlinksmerchantapi.apiary-proxy.com/v4/publisher/18963/offers?&country=US"
headers={'Authorization': access_token,'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url1, headers=headers)

##can i avoid this staging and parse this directly 
f = open(r"C:\\Users\ral\Downloads\\testlinks.csv", "w")
f.write(r.text)
f.close()

with open(r"C:\\Users\ral\Downloads\\testlinks.csv") as f_input:
     d = json.load(f_input)
     df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, record_path='offers')
    
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\ral\Downloads\\offers.csv", index=False)
```

**merchant_details**

```
{'advertiser_id': 9177, 'countries': ['United States'], 'country_codes': ['US'], 'domain': 'heatandcool.com', 'domains': ['heatandcool.com'], 'favourite': False, 'id': 77706, 'merchant_id': 77706, 'metadata': {'description': None, 'logo': 'https://static.testlinks.com/images/merchant_logos/advertiser_logo_9177.gif', 'special_conditions': None}, 'name': 'HeatAndCool.com', 'partner_type': None, 'verticals': ['DIY Home Improvement', 'Appliances', 'Home']}
```

Comment: Hm maybe loop over your offers sub branch and write them?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer and I think it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite my answer because I got much better idea.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(json, record_path='offers')
```

Note: if you're using older version pandas please use `pd.io.json.json_normalize`

Output:

```
coupon_code date_added  description featured    id  offer_ends  offer_starts    offer_type  period  terms   title   url merchant_details.advertiser_id  merchant_details.countries  merchant_details.country_codes  merchant_details.domain merchant_details.domains    merchant_details.favourite  merchant_details.id merchant_details.merchant_id    merchant_details.metadata.description   merchant_details.metadata.logo  merchant_details.metadata.special_conditions    merchant_details.name   merchant_details.partner_type   merchant_details.verticals
0   None    2020-07-06 15:08:51 4th of July Sales Event! Save on Air Condition...   True    1027922 2020-07-09 00:00:00 2020-07-02 00:00:00 sale    finishing_soon  see website for details 40% OFF heating and air conditioning units wit...   https://www.heatandcool.com/sale.html/?TESToff...   9177    [United States] [US]    heatandcool.com [heatandcool.com]   False   77706   77706   None    https://static.TESTlinks.com/images/merchant_l...   None    HeatAndCool.com None    [DIY Home Improvement, Appliances, Home]
```

I noticed that there are many arrays in some columns. If you want to flatten them, you can use `pd.explode()` function.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if isinstance(df[col].values[0], list):
        df = df.explode(col)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
coupon_code date_added  description featured    id  offer_ends  offer_starts    offer_type  period  terms   title   url merchant_details.advertiser_id  merchant_details.countries  merchant_details.country_codes  merchant_details.domain merchant_details.domains    merchant_details.favourite  merchant_details.id merchant_details.merchant_id    merchant_details.metadata.description   merchant_details.metadata.logo  merchant_details.metadata.special_conditions    merchant_details.name   merchant_details.partner_type   merchant_details.verticals
0   None    2020-07-06 15:08:51 4th of July Sales Event! Save on Air Condition...   True    1027922 2020-07-09 00:00:00 2020-07-02 00:00:00 sale    finishing_soon  see website for details 40% OFF heating and air conditioning units wit...   https://www.heatandcool.com/sale.html/?TESToff...   9177    United States   US  heatandcool.com heatandcool.com False   77706   77706   None    https://static.TESTlinks.com/images/merchant_l...   None    HeatAndCool.com None    DIY Home Improvement
1   None    2020-07-06 15:08:51 4th of July Sales Event! Save on Air Condition...   True    1027922 2020-07-09 00:00:00 2020-07-02 00:00:00 sale    finishing_soon  see website for details 40% OFF heating and air conditioning units wit...   https://www.heatandcool.com/sale.html/?TESToff...   9177    United States   US  heatandcool.com heatandcool.com False   77706   77706   None    https://static.TESTlinks.com/images/merchant_l...   None    HeatAndCool.com None    Appliances
2   None    2020-07-06 15:08:51 4th of July Sales Event! Save on Air Condition...   True    1027922 2020-07-09 00:00:00 2020-07-02 00:00:00 sale    finishing_soon  see website for details 40% OFF heating and air conditioning units wit...   https://www.heatandcool.com/sale.html/?TESToff...   9177    United States   US  heatandcool.com heatandcool.com False   77706   77706   None    https://static.TESTlinks.com/images/merchant_l...   None    HeatAndCool.com None    Home
```

Note that any arrays having multiple values will result in more rows. In your example, `merchant_details.verticals` has 3 different values. If you want to flatten the result, they has to be exploded to 3 rows.

Comment: Thank you. So can you please review my code above (i have edited my original post with my code), not sure what is wrong with my code, but i don't get desired output (i.e) i still get nested array for object "merchant_details". How do i flatten that? also, is there a way to directly parse my JSON response as opposed to stage that to a file? .THANK U

Comment: Hi, @stackuser. Actually, I don't understand why you have to stage the response to file. Can you just do `df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path='offers')`? I don't have your data so I can't debug for you. You should be able to figure it out by yourself :) Regarding the array. Please follow my answer, I gave you the code to explod the array already.

Comment: sorry sir.. i'm just getting this error now. JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 26 column 9 (char 1006). same error regardless of using df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path='offers').. nothing changed in the code what was working well until yesturday is throwing is error  :-(. Googled and could find a solution for this.. Is there a way to insert quotes in the JSON response ?

Comment: Looks like you're not correctly using `json.loads()` or `json.dump()`. Python dictionaries use single quote whereas JSON should have double quote. I can't actually debug for you because don't have your environment and the full code.